# Passing checkbox values to controller in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a group of checkboxes which are populated from,the database. Each checkbox value contains a Book `Id`.

Now I have a `Save` button which contains a `ng-click="save()"` function. How can I pass the value of checked book `Id`s to the controller, and how can I catch the array of `Id`s in the controller' `save()` method. How can I bind the checkbox values, with the controller, here?

[image]

Here is the code in the view,

```
<div ng-repeat="bk in Books">
  <input type="checkbox" value={{bk.Id}} ng-checked="$index ===0 ? true : false"/>{{bk.Name}}
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" ng-click="save()"/>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the `Id`s values from the view, you can grab them directly within the controller through the binding mechanism.

Here you have a working sample. Whit this you can get rid of `value={{bk.Id}}` and `ng-checked="$index ===0 ? true : false"`. Also notice how it is initialized the state (checked or unchecked) of the checkbox: `ng-init="bookModel[bk.Id] = $first"` which sets the checkbox checked only for the first element in the list.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Books = [{
        Id: 1,
        Name: "Harry Potrer"
      },
      {
        Id: 2,
        Name: "Python"
      },
      {
        Id: 3,
        Name: "C#"
      }
    ];
    $scope.bookModel = {};
    $scope.save = function() {
      var checkedBooks = [];
      for (var k in $scope.bookModel) {
        if ($scope.bookModel.hasOwnProperty(k) && $scope.bookModel[k]) {
          checkedBooks.push(k);
        }
      }

      //do your stuff with the ids in `checkedBooks`
      alert(checkedBooks);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<span ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<div ng-repeat="bk in Books">

  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="bookModel[bk.Id]" ng-init="bookModel[bk.Id] = $first"/>{{bk.Name}}

</div><br/>
<input type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" ng-click="save()" />

</span>
```